# Trouble installing Scrapy on Windows 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, pip

I am attempting to install Scrapy on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. I started by following the instructions here on Scrapy's documentation.

I got up until the command `'pip install Scrapy'`. Everything works except that it cannot find 'libxml2':

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2     installed?
```

I then visited this website to get the binaries of `libxml2`:

ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit/

The instructions for installation of `libxml2` are here: https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

They state that you should unzip the binaries and place the contents of the `BIN` folder in a path such as `C:\WINDOWS`. I did this. However, after attempting to install Scrapy again, I continue to receive the same error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You might need to add the bin folder of libxml to the PATH environment variable, and then usually you need to restart for that to take effect

Comment: be sure to do `pip install --upgrade pip` if you may have outdated version

Answer (score 5):

Just installled Scrapy on Windows10 x64. It installs only with Python 2.7 on Windows. I used tutotial from [here](https://scraper24x7.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/how-to-install-scrapy-in-windows/).

1. Download from the official site and install `Python 2.7`
2. Open Command promt (`cmd`) with full admin permissions and type:

   `c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py`
   and press `Enter`
3. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ for Python 2.7](http://wordpress.redirectingat.com/?id=725X1342&site=scraper24x7.wordpress.com&xs=1&isjs=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-in%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D44266&xguid=e2ba6ebafc04aa90ae3864b81164e6b6&xuuid=53fae16d454d09b473e2518cc1c44c32&xsessid=dd292a191aea84d8a92f5de88ea34a75&xcreo=0&xed=0&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fscraper24x7.wordpress.com%2F2016%2F03%2F19%2Fhow-to-install-scrapy-in-windows%2F&pref=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F35025437%2Ftrouble-installing-scrapy-on-windows-64-bit%2F39744498%3Fnoredirect%3D1&xtz=-180&abp=1)
4. Install OpenSSL (sorry, can't attach link because of small reputation). Download it to some folder, e.g. C:\Python27\Scripts and execute command from there: `pip install pyOpenSSL-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` (the name of file could not be the same)
5. Install lxml just like previous file: `pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`
6. Install Pywin32
7. And finally, install Scrapy - `pip install Scrapy`

Can recommend to download and install all needed soft for x32 architecture (even if you have x64 system).

Comment: This worked for me, I had to upgrade openssl [pip install pyOpenSSL==16.2.0] and also [pip install pypiwin32]

Answer (score 1):

[It is recommended](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda) to use `conda` to install Scrapy on Windows.
You can download Miniconda from here: http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Once you have `conda` installed you can follow this guide to learn about its subcommands: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html

In short, you can use this commands in your terminal:

1. Create an environment for scrapy: `conda create -n scrapyenv python=2`
2. Enable the scrapy environment: `activate scrapyenv`
3. Install scrapy: `conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy`

**Edit:** Scrapy's conda package has been moved to `conda-forge` channel. Use the command: `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy`

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is what I did to get it installed under Win7/Win10:

- `easy_install lxml`
- `pip install Scrapy`
- install `pywin32` as indicated by the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)

Then, follow the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)  to be sure everything is working

Comment: doesn't work and can't find install instructions for pywin32

Comment: I think the easiest way to get it installed under windows is using conda, please check Rolando's answer (currently the recommended way according to the docs).