# Python 3.5.2 failed with error code 1 OS:Win10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, scrapy, installation

I'm rookie in python, try to install scrapy but here's what python return

> Failed building wheel for lxml

here's the full msg.

> Command
> "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
> -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fisxcup_\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
> '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
> --record C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-qzhtmsde-record\install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fisxcup_\lxml\

There's few solution on StackOverflow, tried but still not work.

Here's what I tried

```
-m pip install wheel
```

success, but doesn't make any difference.

```
-m pip install twisted
```

Fail, here's what python return

> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
>
> Failed building wheel for twisted

```
-m pip install python3-dev
```

Failed, here's the return

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-dev (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for python3-dev

I'm running out of idea, please kindly assist, thanks in advance.

Comment: `install python3-dev`...? `pip` is not `apt-get`

Comment: hmm, I'm using Win10, maybe I have misunderstood.

Comment: answer to installing lxml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027034/how-to-install-lxml-in-python-3-4-on-windows-machine

Comment: What are you doing with the `-m` flag? You should just be able to run `pip install <module>` for whatever you need. Your other error has already been addressed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: For `-m` issue, it works before I uninstall the python without `-m`, but it doesn't work after I install it again.
Thanks for the link, I'm checking that:)

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is an annoying configuration file for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE. I remember having to kludge around or fake it out (just create an empty file); also, it has to be on your system PATH, you may need to edit that (from Control Panel). Read about workarounds for that.

Comment: from scrapy `Python 3 is not supported on Windows. This is because Scrapy core requirement Twisted does not support Python 3 on Windows.` 
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm still fighting with that .bat.:(
BTW, will you suggest to use Linux for coding?

Answer (score 1):

[From the scrapy website](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows)

I dont think your going to have success with python 3 and scrapy.

> Python 3 is not supported on Windows. This is because Scrapy core requirement Twisted does not support Python 3 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

also [from the scrapy website](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda) you could try installing it using anaconda (there's a py35 install), check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35028203/5578348)